# Neo4j How do you add a second custom node and relationship to my existing cypher using apoc.merge.relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So I am working with email data in neo4j. In the example below the `Sender` is a node and `Link`(if email contained a link) is a node, and these nodes are connected by a relationship which uses a column `Outcome` from the csv.  The column `Outcome` can be one of two things: `aborted` or `delivered`.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp.csv") AS row
WITH row WHERE NOT row.Url_Sub_Fld IS null
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From})
MERGE (b:Link { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
WITH a, b, row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel
RETURN a, b
```

Which returns:

[image]

I would like to take this a step forward and add the `Recipient` who received the `Links` and a second relationship from another column.  The `Recipient` is in the `To` column of the csv, and the relationship is from the `Outcome2` column which can be either `to` or `failed`.

My desired output would be:

[image]

I have tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp.csv") AS row
WITH row WHERE NOT row.Url_Sub_Fld IS null
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From})
MERGE (b:Url { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a, b, c, row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b, row.Outcome2, {}, {},c) YIELD rel
RETURN a, b, c
```

as well as adding a second `WITH` and `CALL` but that doesn't work either.  I would like to do this all in one script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do too much at once. You don't need to MERGE the entire pattern in one call, use two calls to the proc to merge one segment at a time:

```
...
WITH a, b, c, row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
RETURN a, b, c
```